# '[warning] Drush command terminated abnormally.'

Tags: drush

Drush won't run at the command line in any Drupal 8 subdomain installation:
`[warning] Drush command terminated abnormally.`

I am using GreenGeeks hosting for several Drupal 8.8.7 sites, one 8.8.6 site, one 9.0.0 site as subdomains, e.g. subdomain.domain.com and each subdomain is configured to point to the /web subdirectory (by installation default).

- I installed Drush using this guide: https://www.greengeeks.com/support/article/how-do-i-install-drush/
- I used composer successfully to install all above sites, by following the same guide and supplementing with version specific installation instructions, e.g. `composer create-project drupal/recommended-project:8.8.7 bingo`
- I updated my `.bashrc` file, by using the same guide, i.e.

```
# User specific aliases and functions
alias drush='~/drush/vendor/bin/drush'
```

The D8 websites work fine. HOWEVER, if I navigate to the command line of any of the 8.x drupal sites, then Drush will not run as example below:

```
acctname@svrname [~/public_html/bingo]# drush version
 [warning] Drush command terminated abnormally.
acctname@svrname [~/public_html/bingo]#
```

Drush runs NORMALLY at the /public_html directory, but there is no drupal installed there:

```
acctname@svrname [~/public_html]# drush version
 Drush version : 10.2.2
acctname@svrname [~/public_html]#
```

Drush ALSO RUNS NORMALLY at the Drupal9 website:

```
acctname@svrname [~/public_html/drupal9]# drush version
 Drush version : 10.2.2
acctname@svrname [~/public_html/drupal9]#
```

THE FOLLOWING INFO MAY NOT BE RELATED...
HOWEVER, at the risk of distraction, the errorlog indicates a drush-related error for the D9 website and the website suddenly shows this error (it used to work):
`The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.`

And the error_log reports this:
`Error: Class 'Drush\Log\DrushLog' not found in /home/projects/public_html/drupal9/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php on line 257`

...but Drush still runs normally

Comment: So you have Composer-managed projects? Then you `cd yourproject` and add Drush to a project locally `composer require drush/drush`. Then you call it directly from inside the project `vendor/drush/drush/drush cr`. Optionally install the global Drush Launcher to be able to simply run `drush cr`.

Comment: As lenymannx said, with composer managed projects, drush should be a managed by composer just like all your other contrib modules, libraries, etc. I'd recommend uninstalling drush globally (undo the steps you followed in the 7 year old guide), then remove the alias in your `.bashrc`, then follow the steps leymannx laid out.

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/161966/what-can-we-do-to-remedy-the-unrecoverable-error-we-encounter-for-any-drush-comm